# Set Proof:$A \cup B=A\cup(B\cap A^c)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A and B be elements of some universal set. Use a proof to prove the following.
$A \cup B=A\cup(B\cap A^c)$

How would I prove this. I know that I would have show that

- $A \cup B \subseteq A\cup(B\cap A^c)$
- $A\cup(B\cap A^c) \subseteq A \cup B$

But don't know where to go from here.

Comment: You've decrypted $=$ into two $\subseteq$'s. Cool. That's a really common approach, and it probably works just as well here. What's the next step of _that same very common approach_? In other words, what does $\subseteq$ _mean_?

Comment: @Arthur I understand that I have to show that they are basically a subset of each other, but I don't know the process of showing that they are subsets of each other.

Comment: And what does "subset" _mean_?

Comment: Proof verification is for when you wrote down the proof and want someone to help you verify its correctness. The set theory tag is for questions about more advanced set theory.

Comment: Try to show that if "X" is an arbitrary element in one set, then X is also in ther other set.

Answer (score 0):

I show you the proof for $A \cup B \subseteq A\cup(B\cap A^c)$. To this end let $x \in A \cup B .$

Case 1: $x \in A$. Then we have $x \in A\cup(B\cap A^c)$.

Case 2: $x \notin A$. Then we have $x \in B$ and $x \in A^c$. Thus $x \in B\cap A^c $ and therefore $x \in A\cup(B\cap A^c)$.